# Back button press list-view item becomes double in android

Tags: android

this is my async task :

```
class download extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // progress.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EmployeeVisit.this);
                pDialog.setTitle("While Data Fetching");
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                pDialog.show();
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                try {
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
                    request.addProperty("Employee", "EMP01");
                    Bean C = new Bean();
                    PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
                    pi.setName("Bean");
                    pi.setValue(C);
                    pi.setType(C.getClass());
                    request.addProperty(pi);
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;
                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
                    androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
                    envelope.addMapping(NAMESPACE, "Panchayat",
                            new Bean().getClass());
                    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
                    Bean[] personobj = new Bean[result.getPropertyCount()];
                    Bean beanobj = new Bean();
                    for (int j = 0; j < personobj.length; j++) {
                        SoapObject pii = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(j);
                        beanobj.City = pii.getProperty(0).toString();
                        beanobj.EmployeeID = pii.getProperty(1).toString();
                        beanobj.RouteNumber = pii.getProperty(2).toString();
                        beanobj.SpokeCode = pii.getProperty(3).toString();
                        beanobj.VisitMasterId = pii.getProperty(4).toString();
                        personobj[j] = beanobj;
                        city = beanobj.City;
                        employyeid = beanobj.EmployeeID;
                        routenumber = beanobj.RouteNumber;
                        spokecode = beanobj.SpokeCode;
                        visitmaster = beanobj.VisitMasterId;
                        stringArray.add(city);
                        routestringArray.add(routenumber);

                        hashmap.put(city, visitmaster);
                        hashmap1.put(city, routenumber);
                    }
                    arr = new int[routestringArray.size()];

                    for (int i = 0; i < routestringArray.size(); i++) {
                        arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(routestringArray.get(i));// this
                                                                            // will
                                                                            // work!!
                        System.out.println(arr[i]);
                    }

                    leastroutenumber = leastnumber(arr);


                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                super.onPostExecute(result);

                String array[] = new String[stringArray.size()];

                for (int j = 0; j < stringArray.size(); j++) {
                    array[j] = stringArray.get(j);
                }

                Myadapter adMyadapter = new Myadapter(EmployeeVisit.this, array);
                listview.setAdapter(adMyadapter);
                pDialog.dismiss();

            }

        }
```

I am calling this in Oncreate{new download().execute}  and onressume(new download().execute)
 both method but when launch application first time then both method call please tell me where I am doing wrong:

```
public class EmployeeVisit extends Activity {
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

new download().execute();
}
} 

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onResume();


            new download().execute();

    }
```

please suggest me how to call this

Comment: look at the life-cycleof Activity http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html and you will find the answer by your own.

Comment: actully i want there is A and B i am going from A to B On listview item click on b i apply finish() button click now i it should go back in Previous Actvity A and i want to call again download().execute(); where i have to Put this ? while when we launch first time actvity A then both method call @arashjavan i did same

Comment: @ResearcheDevelopment please mark your question as answered if the suggestions below was successful.

Comment: no when call finish then listviewitem becomes double while its should remove 1 item from listview if we again launch app then it remove

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `download().execute();` in both `onCreate` and `onResume` function. Call this in `onResume` only.

Comment: which one @vinita jain

Comment: actully i want there is A and B i am going from A to B On listview item click on b i apply finish() button click  now i it should go back in Previous Actvity A and i want to call again download().execute(); where i have to Put this  ? while when we launch first time actvity A then both method call

Comment: @vinita Welcome to Stackoverflow :) Either describe a little more if you're posting an answer or post it as a comment. Thank you :)

Comment: @Research Development  : When you call download().execute() in onCreate as well as in onResume method it is called for twice. Because when an activity is created first it will call onCreate method then it call onResume. So put download().execute only in onReume function, So when u come back from other activity also it will show updated data and remove duplication also.

Comment: Ok i did but what Problem is here when we go back then many time onresume method call and our listview itembecomes many duplicate item

Comment: Ok, the problem is every time when the asyn task is called u fill the response in same arraylist which is already filled. So in, onPreExecute() function initialize your arraylist again.

stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
routestringArray = new ArrayList<String>();

Answer (score 0):

try to use "onSaveInstanceState":

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
   super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
   outState.putString("message", "Activity was startetd once");
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  if( savedInstanceState == null ) {
     new download().execute();
  }
}
```

[onSaveInstanceState Doc (Google)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Another approach could be to use "startActivityForResult"

Start Acitvity B from Activity A:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);
```

finish activity B like this:

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
// optional intent, if you want give something back to the starter Activity
returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);

// If no intent needed -> setResult(RESULT_OK);
setResult(RESULT_OK,returnIntent);
finish();
```

Catch the result in acitivity A again:

```
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1) {
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                new download().execute();
            }
            if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Write your code if there's no result
            }
        }
    }
```

So you can delete

```
new download().execute();
```

from

```
onResume()
```

Comment: its ok But again onresume method call when i  open app very first itme

Comment: when i am going from A->B and in B i am calling finish then come back then in A which method will call ?

Comment: returnIntent.putExtra("result",result);  what result value we should put @arash javan

Comment: @Research Development returnIntent.putExtra("result",result); is optional if you want to give something back to the starter activity (A in your case).